# elininate some lines from data set

Tags: loops, perl

I am rying to get some line out of my data set.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days); 
my @just_ecps;
my @folder_dates;
my @ecp_dot_tee_array = `grep ISLAND ~/data/files/grit.t`;
foreach (@ecp_dot_tee_array){
      ($ecp, undef, undef, undef, undef, undef) = split (/\s+/, $_);
         push (@just_ecps, $ecp);
}
for ($h = 1; $h <= 5; $h++){

   my (undef, undef, undef, $day, $month, $year) = localtime();
   $year+=1900;
   $month+=1;
   ($year, $month, $day) = Add_Delta_Days($year, $month, $day, -$h );
   if ($month < 10 ){
      $month = "0$month";
   }
   if ($day < 10 ){
      $day = "0$day";
   }
push (@folder_dates, "$year$month$day");
}

for ( $j=0; $j <=$#just_ecps ; $j++){
   for ($x=0; $x<=$#folder_dates ; $x++){
      open FILEHANDLE , "zmore /data/ibprod/archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]  /ghistogram.gz | ";
      @archive_average = (<FILEHANDLE>);
      foreach $line(@archive_average){
         if ($line =~ /ave:\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s/){
            print $1;
            sleep 1;
            print "\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is what i get when i run the program - i am trying to get the 'cannot read the > files out of the data set

```
% ./read_in_ghistogram2
0.00414601
0.0044511
0.00387373
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110814/islnd1/ghistogram.gz: No such  file or directory
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110813/islnd1/ghistogram.gz: No such file or directory
0.00309721
0.00302753
0.00307702
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110814/islnd2/ghistogram.gz: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110813/islnd2/ghistogram.gz: No such file or directory 
0.00324729
0.00295381
0.00301736
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110814/islnd3/ghistogram.gz: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/zmore: line 52: /home/data/archive/20110813/islnd3/ghistogram.gz: No such file or directory
```

I tried filtering them out of the while loop, but it does not work, and ther is not line 52 in the program, it only goes to 42

```
for ( $j=0; $j <=$#just_ecps ; $j++){
   for ($x=0; $x<=$#folder_dates ; $x++){
      #print "/home/ibprod_archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]/ghistogram.gz";
      open FILEHANDLE , "zmore /data/archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]/ghistogram.gz | ";
      while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
          next if ($_ =~ '/No such file or directory/');
          push (@archive_average,$_);
          foreach $line(@archive_average){
             if ($line =~ /\save:\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s/){
               print $line;
               sleep 1;
             }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Line 52` refers to the line in the `zmore` script, not in your perl script.

To fix your issue, test if the file exists in your perl script before handing it over to something else.

```
my $archive = "/data/archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]/ghistogram.gz";
next unless (-r $archive);
```

`-r` checks both that the file exists and is readable by the current user. So `next unless (-r $file)` will go to the next iteration of the loop unless the file exists and is readable.

(This is racy - if something is removing (or changing ownership of) those files while you are trying to read them, `open` can still fail. If this is not security sensitive, then that's not too much of a worry, but keep that in mind.)

Two tips:

- `zmore` is meant to be used by humans, not scripts. You script does not care one bit if the output is paginated. So you should be using `gunzip -c $file` (or maybe `gzip -cd` if you don't have `gunzip`, not sure about that one).
- Always check that `open` succeeded, otherwise you'll be trying to manipulate invalid filehandles at some point, which will get you more errors. And always `close` what you opened.

So I'd change your script to:

```
my $archive = "/data/archive/$folder_dates[$x]/$just_ecps[$j]/ghistogram.gz";
next unless (-r $archive);
if (!open(FILEHANDLE, "<", "gunzip -c $archive|")) {
  print STDERR "Error processing $archive: $!\n"; # optional
  next;
}
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
  ...
}
close FILEHANDLE;
```

Lastly, the `zmore` error message is being printed to STDERR. If all you want to do is hide those messages (rather than fixing them), simply redirect that to a log file (or `/dev/null`):

```
% ./read_in_ghistogram2 2> errors.log
```

Comment: my boss directed me to use the zmore, so i really like the gunzip -c .

Comment: i have not run the code yet - i am nt sure that i understand the 'not!' in front of the open statement....thank you though

Comment: `open` returns `0` if it is successful, non-zero otherwise. `0` is false in boolean context, `!0` is true. So `!open(...)` is true if `open` failed.

Comment: If you want to make it more explicit, use `my $rc = open(...); if ($rc ne 0) { # open failed }`. But the `if (!open(...))` construct is relatively common.